# How to run the service on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the function inside service in angular module but how do I run the service on page load. I am not using any controller here

Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myTmoApppdl", [])
        .service('populatePageObjsService', function () {

            var self = this;

            //digitalData is a global object
            self.populatePage = function (digitalData) {
                var dataPageObject = document.getElementById('metaJson').getAttribute("data-pageObject");
                var jsonPageObject = JSON.parse(dataPageObject);

                for (var key in jsonPageObject.page.pageInfo) {
                    var value = jsonPageObject.page.pageInfo[key];
                    if (digitalData.page.pageInfo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        digitalData.page.pageInfo[key] = value;
                    }
                }
                console.log("Page data populated successfully: ", digitalData.page.pageInfo);
            }();
        });
```

I tried using the `()` after function but it didn't execute the function

Update:

```
var app = angular.module("myTmoApppdl", []).run(function () {
    app.service('populatePageObjsService', function () {
        var self = this;
        self.populatePage = function (digitalData) {
            var dataPageObject = document.getElementById('metaJson').getAttribute("data-pageObject");
            var jsonPageObject = JSON.parse(dataPageObject);

            for (var key in jsonPageObject.page.pageInfo) {
                var value = jsonPageObject.page.pageInfo[key];
                if (digitalData.page.pageInfo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    digitalData.page.pageInfo[key] = value;
                }
            }
            console.log("Page data populated successfully: ", digitalData.page.pageInfo);
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your service method in `.run()` block

```
var app = angular.module("myTmoApppdl", []);   
app.run(function(populatePageObjsService){ // inject your service here
   //use your service here
});
app.service('populatePageObjsService', function() {
     // your service code here
});
```

Comment: Is there any other ways also to achieve the same. Just for info. Thanks

Comment: It should work. Can you replicate the issue somewhere for me to look at

Comment: Please check the updated question with code I have tried with changes

Comment: Not like this. Updated answer for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

With **[run module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)**

Simple example

```
var app = angular.module("myTmoApppdl", [])
  .run(function(populatePageObjsService) {
    populatePageObjsService.init();
  })
  .service('populatePageObjsService', function() {

    var self = this;

    self.init = function() {
      alert("run");
    };
  });
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/p7kEZUgfYCgr5ReXFx1O)

Answer (score 1):

Since an AngularJS service is **singleton**, you can be sure that your function will only be executed once, but you have to bear in mind that it is also **lazily instantiated** - Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it - [source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

With this in mind, if a service is somehow self-reliable (for example, fetching the user's country via an API call - since this can be executed only once at the start of the app and it's unlikely for the data to change), besides the usual service bindings, you can also put logic in there.

I've edited your code to showcase this approach.

```
angular
    .module("myTmoApppdl", [])
    // populatePageObjsService needs to be injected somewhere otherwise it won't get instantiated
    .service('populatePageObjsService', function() {
        //////////////
        // Bindings //
        //////////////

        var self = this;

        //digitalData is a global object
        self.populatePage = function(digitalData) {
            var dataPageObject = document.getElementById('metaJson').getAttribute("data-pageObject");
            var jsonPageObject = JSON.parse(dataPageObject);

            for (var key in jsonPageObject.page.pageInfo) {
                var value = jsonPageObject.page.pageInfo[key];
                if (digitalData.page.pageInfo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    digitalData.page.pageInfo[key] = value;
                }
            }
            console.log("Page data populated successfully: ", digitalData.page.pageInfo);
        };

        ///////////////
        // Run Block //
        ///////////////

        // Calling the desired function.
        self.populatePage(digitalData);
    });
```

Comment: Still needs to be injected, and no controller use on the question.

Comment: @JoseRocha True. Without injecting the service it won't get initialized.

Comment: @CosminAbabei  Make an edition stating that so i can give you an upvote ;)

Comment: @JoseRocha Thanks! I've added a reference to the fact that services are lazily instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.element(document).ready(function () {`

```
// your code here
```

`});`